# imagemagick php writeImages always give me 1 page result

Tags: php, imagemagick

I am using imageMagick extension for php 5.4

> magick module version 3.1.0RC1 ImageMagick 6.7.7-10 2013-09-01 Q16 
>   ImageMagick release date  2013-09-01

Trying this simple snippet:

```
$images = array(
    '1.jpg',
    '2.jpg'
);
$pdf = new Imagick($images);
$pdf->setImageFormat('pdf');
if (!$pdf->writeImages('combined.pdf', true)) {
    die('Could not write!');
}
```

Always gives me 1 PAGE PDF file.

(I tried various ways to acheive that, including trying to create GIF animation and it always generated me 1 single frame or 1 sigle page).

When I try on SSH

```
convert 1.jpg 2.jpg combined.pdf
```

This works great: what am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try appendimage function of Imagemagick

http://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.appendimages.php